# Can I introduce the output of variables in the message of asserts

Tags: python

I am doing some validation of the input data of one program I have created. I am doing this with assert. If assertion arises I want to know in which part of the data occurs so I want to get the value that arises the assertion.

```
assert all(isinstance(e, int)
           for l1 in sequence.values()
           for l2 in l1 for e in l2),"Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in  '{l2}'"
# This code doesn't work
```

Comment: It's not that far off. The `assert` statement is little more than a wrapper around an `if` statement that can raise an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not when using `all` as it does not expose the "iteration variable". You will need an explicit, nested loop. You also forgot the `f''` prefix to denote an f-string:

```py
for l1 in [['a']]:
    for l2 in l1:
        for e in l2:
            assert isinstance(e, int), f"Values of the dictionnary 
aren't lists of integers. Assert found in  '{l2}'"
```

```
AssertionError: Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in  'a'
```

Comment: Hi SeepSpace. Thanks for your help. This work in jupyter notebook but when I run the script I get this assert isinstance(e, int), f"Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in line number  '{count_lines}' of the bed file"
                                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MDB Seems like an old python version without f strings

Comment: Sorry. I dont know why I was running python 2

Comment: @MDB For the exact same behaviour, wrap everything in a `if __DEBUG__:` if block.

Comment: The issue isn't the `all` function, but the fact that it's operating on a *generator expression*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an assignment expression to capture the "witness" to `all` returning `False`. To do this, we'll do away with some generators. We'll use `map` to apply `isinstance` to each value of `l2`, which lets us capture the current value of `l2` in a variable that will persist for use in the `assert` message. We'll also use `itertools.chain` to eliminate the need for the name `l1`.

```
from itertools import chain


def is_int(x):
    return isinstance(x, int)


sequence = {
    'key1': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    'key2': [[7, 8, 9], ['a', 11, 12]]
}

assert all(all(map(is_int, (witness := l2)))                
           for l2 in chain(*sequence.values())), \
       f"Values of the dictionary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in '{witness}'"
```

With a little modification, you can iterate over `sequence.items()` so that you can also capture the key whose list contains the offending `l2`. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I would unpack all your `e's` and then do an assertion:

```
# Assuming l1 is a list of lists
l1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], ["7", 8, 9]]


# TO TEST SUBLISTS
l2 = [x for x in l1]
for sublist in l2:
    assert all([isinstance(e, int) for x in sublist]), 
        f'Values isn\'t a list of integers: {sublist}'


# TO TEST FOR INDIVIDUAL VALUES
all_e = [y for x in l1 for y in x]

# To raise an error on each value:
for e in all_e:
    assert(isinstance(e, int)), f'Value isn\'t an int: {e}'

# To operate in one line
assert all([isinstance(e, int) for x in all_e]), 
    f'Values aren\'t a list of integers: {all_e}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could remember it in a variable that does leak out simply by inserting `if [witness := l2]`:

```
sequence = {                             # thanks chepner
    'key1': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    'key2': [[7, 8, 9], ['a', 11, 12]]
}

assert all(isinstance(e, int)
           for l1 in sequence.values()
           for l2 in l1 if [witness := l2]
           for e in l2), f"Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in  '{witness}'"
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 6, in <module>
    assert all(isinstance(e, int)
AssertionError: Values of the dictionnary aren't lists of integers. Assert found in  '['a', 11, 12]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NbsIwEITveYoRFwdphWTTH4rEoS/RS@SDBZti1bKp7YAixLOnjkt7aOc4@@3MnMZ8DH69OcVpSvw5sN8zdrg2KBIfPEqxRddJgiKsNaF7IDwSnrSmX0ZV5pmwIbzMjDCCIMuTVFo3t6YxKXHMMM61Nlmfsik9LROsz8uac1cfIpwsNn7WrM7GDZza/5iasRnu0V1s9pwStrvi678oV1ItCf3ircYh9MhHxsHusw3emzjCRPYiw9mU671s43eOaYXX7/l9GPxhjoK43gtvYjFNXw)

Could also use `(witness := l2)` here instead of `[witness := l2]`, but the latter is applicable in general.

Comment: What does `witness` do in this solution?

Comment: @ybressler_simon It remembers the last value of `l2`. So it can be used in the assertion error message instead of `l2`, like I did.